# Can you explain to me why the if / else statement is not working correctly?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to check if a user exists and indicate his age, but I cannot figure out why he is entering the user's age and the "you don't have such a user". Here is my code below.

```js
const users = [{
    name: "Jane",
    age: 25
  },
  {
    name: "John",
    age: 29
  },
  {
    name: "Jack",
    age: 35
  }
];


const user = document.getElementById("userName");

function getAge() {
  users.find(item => item.name == user.value ? console.log(item.age) : console.log("you don't have such a user"));
}
```

```html
<input id="userName" type="text">
<button onclick="getAge()">check</button>
```

If I type "Jack", it returns 2 times that you do not have such a user, and then the age.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to read the value of the input field and not the input field itself. Also you should put it inside the ageFunction because otherwise it would get the value when the page loads and there the value is empty

```
function getAge() {
  const userN = document.getElementById("userName").value;
```

As next remove the console log's from the find and just do a query inside it. Check which users name is equals to the input userN

```
let foundedUser = users.find(item => item.name === userN);
```

Finally you should check if there was a user found with this name

```
if (foundedUser !== null && foundedUser !== undefined ) {
  console.log(foundedUser.age)
}else {
  console.log("You don't have such a user")
}
```

Also I would recommend using an event listener

```
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', getAge);
```

```js
const users = [{
    name: "Jane",
    age: 25
  },
  {
    name: "John",
    age: 29
  },
  {
    name: "Jack",
    age: 35
  }
];

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', getAge);

function getAge() {
  const userN = document.getElementById("userName").value;


  let foundedUser = users.find(item => item.name === userN);
  if (foundedUser !== null && foundedUser !== undefined ) {
    console.log(foundedUser.age)
  }else {
    console.log("You don't have such a user")
  }

}
```

```html
<input id="userName" type="text">
<button>check</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

Change the function to

```
function getAge() {
   let a=users.find(item => item.name === user.value )
   if(a)
   console.log(a.age)
    else
    console.log("you don't have such a user"));
    }
```

Comment: can you log user and post it?

Comment: I have already found a solution, thank all of you

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `===` for comparison

Answer (score 1):

This is not the most efficient code, but it just works.

```html
<input id="userName" type="text" value="Jack">
<button onclick="getAge()">check</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
const users = [
        {name: "Jane",age: 25},
        {name: "John",age: 29},
        {name: "Jack",age: 35}
];
        
const user = document.getElementById("userName");
function getAge() {
    the_user = users.find(item => item.name == user.value);
    if (the_user) {console.log(the_user.age);}
    else {console.log("you don't have such a user");}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you want to do:

```js
const users = [
  {
    name: "Jane",
    age: 25,
  },
  {
    name: "John",
    age: 29,
  },
  {
    name: "Jack",
    age: 35,
  },
];

function getAge() {
  let user = document.getElementById("userName");
  let result = users.find((item) =>
    item.name == user.value
  );
  (result !== undefined) ? console.log(`user ${result.name} whose age is ${result.age} found`): console.log("user not found");
}
```

```html
<input id="userName" type="text"> 

<button onclick="getAge()">check</button>
```